# You cannot delete this project because it is linked with a Dialogflow agent

Tags: google-contacts-api

I've a problem with the google developer console: I'cant delete the project because it is linked with a Dialogflow agent, but this agent doesn't exist. I've tried cancel my dialogflow account, but it doesn't work.

That's the error message:

*You cannot delete this project because it is linked with a Dialogflow agent. Please follow the link to Dialogflow and delete the agent: https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/#/agent/242efd62-119b-4ae5-b71e-xxxxxxxxxxxx*

Thank you so much for the support!